# Actions on an instance object passed to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, partial

I have an obj @files which sometimes contain one set of data(one file) and sometimes it contains many files.

I have a create.js.erb and this is what I do at the moment.

```
<% if @files.new_record? %>
  alert("Failed to upload: <%= j @files.errors.full_messages.join(', ').html_safe %>");
<% else %>
  $(".container").append('<div id="cfile"><%= j render(@files) %></div>');
<% end %>
```

Then I have a partial called _file.html.erb

```
<%= file.name %>
<%= file_.id %>
```

This all works fine but I'm running into problems trying to create a partial for different types of files.

I want to be able to do something like

```
if file.first.type == image # (Even If the come in groups they would be the same type so i just need one .type field from one of them.)
     $(".different_container").append(render different partial here);
else if file.first.type == doc 
     $(".another_container").append(render another partial here);
```

How would I go about this?
Please ask if i haven't explained something clearly.

Comment: So you have @files - is that an internal variable? Is that the result of a method? Is that an association? If you defined your own `#files` method you could just have it wrap the results, before returning, in to an Array using `Array(files)`. If `files` is a single element, it will turn it in to a single element array. If it's an array, it does nothing.

Comment: thanks for your comment,@files is an instance variable gotten from the create action, it can return many files because it's a multi file uploader so it can return one or many. @files = current_user.files.create(params[:file_handler])

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: So what is it exactly that you're stumbling over? Is it that you're not sure how to get the `type` because sometimes @files is a single item? And calling `.first.type` blows up?

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now. See my answer for some more explanation. Let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that @files can be multiple items or a single item. Before you access it, you can wrap it in `Array()`, like this:

```
file_type = Array(@files).first.type
if file_type == :something
elsif file_type == :something_else
end
```

What `Array()` does is it tries to convert the argument passed to it in to an array. If you pass it a single object, it will return an array with that one object in it. If you pass it an array, it does nothing.

```
>> Array(1) # => [1]
>> Array(Object.new) # => [Object]
>> Array([1,2,3]) # => [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Oh thank you soo much, i would never have thought of that, i actually had the type in an hstore but it still worked great with hstore queries. Thanks a ton :)